# Spreadsheet Excel Writer, Character Set issue?

Tags: php, excel, writer

I am writing data to xls sheet.

When i write some Latin characters like this

> POINT ÅØÆ LN

here is what written in sheet

> POINT Ã¥Ã¸Ã¦

Here is what i have tried.

```
 $worksheet = &$workbook->addWorksheet($wbname);

  $worksheet->setInputEncoding('ISO-8859-15');
```

Have tired utf-8 and some other character sets.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHPExcel, here is the link:
https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples